# can't launch debug window to check code

Tags: c#, forms, debugging

I'm new to Visual Studio, I just started using it for my programming class. I downloaded C# 2010 from the website, and every time I try to debug the code the form window doesn't show up as the black box with the output, rather it displays a blank gray box. I have no clue how to check my code, I haven't been able to find anyone else with this problem, someone please help!

Comment: Did you add any break points to the code? Did you start the program with out debugging (Ctrl + F5)?

Comment: If you are writing console application just add `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of your *Main()* method to see the output window.

Answer (score 2):

As you are assuming a black box - mean you want to start with a Console Application
and your are getting a gray box - mean you had chosen the Windows Form Application.

So What to do you is :

Select a Console Application.
Like File -> New -> Project -> Console Application.

Put breakpoints on your code. and press F5 to run your application in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

Put a debug point in the code on the left side where you have a empty column.. Then click F5 to run the code with debugging.. It will stop when the break point is hit..

Check this [tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the solution configuration set to `Debug` ? Or is it `Release`? Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx) for details.